# How to factory reset the phone so it doesnt ask me for password / google login when i configure it?

Tags: android, adb, samsung

I reseted my phone with recovery mode, but i cant use it because it's asking me to log in to my google account i dont remember the password for.

I cannot connect it to adb because i don't have a way to enable USB debugging option. What should I do?

Phone model: Samsung a20

Comment: What you say makes no sense. You can use usb debugging without any account.